# How is the name of an effect size chosen?

Tags: terminology, effect-size, history

The wikipedia page about effect sizes lists many effect sizes ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size). Obviously, it's often the case that names are partly constructed by the name of the person who defined the effect size (Pearson's r, Cohen's d, Cramer's v, Hedges' g, Glass' $\Delta$, etc. ), but I'm wondering how the letter is chosen.

I guess it may vary between effect sizes (in particular when some of them do not include isolated letters or the inventor's name, like the odds ratio), but is there generally a rationale behind the choice of a letter or a name (barring the "inventor" name), or is it generally arbitrary?

For example, why do some names include a Latin letter and others a Greek letter? Does the choice of a name somehow relate to their "family" (correlation, differences between means, association between categorical variables)? Is the letter in any way useful to get some information about the nature or statistical properties of the effect size? (e.g. without looking up what Cohen's d is, does the letter "d" tell me anything about this effect size?)

Comment: Interesting question, though it has little to do with actual statistics and more with etymology I guess. A lot of it stems from the convention to use Greek letters for mathematical variables, where it might as well come down to whatever's still available or what you think looks nice, in that order. Because *writing* Greek symbols takes effort (and/or TeX support), a lot of them seem to have become Latinized, e.g. I am used to seeing Pearson's correlation as $\rho$ and not r. At the end of the day, as long as the convention is sufficiently clear to convey what you mean, anything goes..

Comment: It's pretty much down to however it was first proposed, and what became popular in the literature.

Comment: @Pbulls interesting! My question is related to statistics, because I was wondering if the name could convey by itself some information about the statistical properties of the effect size, for example does it give some info about their "family". (Which is not the case, according to your answer and Stephan Kolassa's answer!)

Comment: I actually invented a measure (not that it ever got widely used) and I went to the Hebrew alphabet and chose aleph. See Flom, Friedman & Strauss (2004) A New Measure of Linkage Between Two Subnetworks.